# Does buffer-overflow causes segfault only when an important pointer is overwritten?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, buffer-overflow

Assuming I have a program that declares a `char buffer[size]` and another variable and uses `gets(buffer);` to write data into `buffer`. If `gets` is provided with too long input, then it will spill out from the buffer, into that next variable (assuming that variable is located in the next address after `buffer`):

```
void f(){
    char str[12] = "hello_world";
    char buffer[1];

    gets(buffer); // provided with a random char and then "hello_kitty"

    printf("str = %s\n", str); // no crash. Just prints "hello_kitty" as expected
}
```

When running this with the "legal input" (meaning - not overflowing the 2nd buffer) this was OK. It was OK even when I overflowed the buffer a little bit, but after entering too much the program crashed.

As I understand, this (meaning - not overflowing the 2nd buffer) shouldn't cause any crashes. What might cause a crash is corrupting the memory where the instruction pointer is kept, so it will now point to a non-valid address (is this a page fault?).

Is this correct? can a bad write that affects none of the stack/frame/instruction pointers cause a crash?

Comment: Writing outside of bounds and overwrite another variable leads to undefined behavior, but overwriting program counter return address which is on stack as well is kinda overkill

Comment: "can a bad write that affects none of the stack/frame/instruction pointers cause a crash?" --> Yes - of course it is possible.  It is UB.  Consider an implementation that employs bounds checking on arrays.

Comment: sure it's UB, but on my machine, this is what actually happens. I'm trying to understand what would actually happen on machine such as mine in similar cases, and why. UB doesn't mean I don't know what would happen, it only tells me it's left for the compiler designers to figure out what to do

Comment: No, that is not true. "Undefined behavior" is something the compiler designers *don't care* (well, should not care) about.

Comment: Your machine, compiler, OS are unknown.  UB is not "left for the compiler designers to figure out what to do".  UB allows designers to not even care what happens with code that is non-compliant.

Comment: I'm using a x64-based processor. will this info help in determining what and why this happens?

Comment: You can step through the disassembly on your machine and figure out exactly what is happening. Not that it has much of practical value except of mastering assembly and debugger.

Comment: the compiler is free to put buffer before or after str, and it's also free to put some buffer between them. Nothing is guaranteed to happen

Comment: It is for the tough gamblers. Imagine that you have pacemaker implanted and one day you meet the lead designer. And he tells you: we know that we have some UBs in the firmware. We overwrite the allocated memories - but only a bit. Some , but not worry only the few local variables are used uninitialised, we know that, but the deadline was very tough so we did not time to change it. Only very small percentage of the patients die because of it. You do not have to worry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to read [smashing the stack for fun and profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) by Aleph One, you'd know that *computers get hacked* by *overflowing buffers (and overwriting important pointers)*...

... and as the article covers, there's no *segfault* because part of the exploit code is often `exit(0);`, providing the attacker can't recover the program in a better way.

So to answer your questions:

> is this a page fault?

Not necessarily. Such a concept needn't exist in the world of C.

> Is this correct? can a bad write that affects none of the stack/frame/instruction pointers cause a crash?

Sure, but that's not to be relied upon. This is why people suggest that *undefined behaviours* such as *buffer overflows* can cause really drastic things to occur (such as *dragons* and *nuclear holocausts*).

I can see from other comments the intent behind this question:

- > [well known. Trying to understand how to exploit it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740014/does-buffer-overflow-causes-segfault-only-when-an-important-pointer-is-overwritt/45741883#comment78437778_45740103)
- > [... overwriting the address the ret operations wants to return to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740014/does-buffer-overflow-causes-segfault-only-when-an-important-pointer-is-overwritt/45741883#comment78439380_45740580)

In this case, you're on the right track... The one thing you're missing is that those *random characters* you mentioned are machine code, and the *instruction pointer* needs to be overwritten to point at that machine code. Aleph One covers this in greater detail, though your mileage will certainly vary as it's an ancient document.

If it weren't for this problem with many undefined behaviours, **all** of the experts of C would likely be intercepting signals to recover their software without an issue, but alas, C is not Java... Best ye follow the examples of the experts and *avoid undefined behaviours*...

Assume that a decent guide will try to help you avoid undefined behaviours where possible. There's at least one decent guide in the form of a book we refer to as a "bible" of forms, partially because it was written by some authoritative people. It has a large, blue "C" on it, and nowadays "SECOND EDITION" is written in red...

Be it an exercise to ye to find that book. I have confidence.

Comment: Buffer overflows are far from the only way computers get hacked.  That sentence might be misleading.

Comment: I didn't say they're "the only way computers get hacked", but you're right... it might be misleading, in the same way any sentence can be misleading if you inject non-existent words into it.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question concisely, no.  Read on for a longer answer.

The most typical way that a buffer overflow results in a segmentation fault is that the overflowed buffer resides on the stack and the overflow overwrites the return pointer.  When the return pointer is popped back into the instruction pointer upon function return, the segmentation fault usually occurs because the *processor tries to read memory that you do not have access to.*

That final sentence is quite important.  The overwrite of the return pointer is just one way that a segmentation fault can occur.  In fact, any buffer overflow that overwrites a memory address that is *later used to access memory* can result in a segmentation fault or, if it is an attempt to write to the memory, an access violation.

For example, imagine that you have a structure allocated on the heap.  That structure takes this form:

```
 struct sample_struct {
   char bytes[20];
   struct sample_struct *next;
 };
```

If data is copied into the `bytes` member without properly verifying bounds, the next item in memory will be the `next` pointer.  If this pointer is overwritten and subsequently an attempt is made to read from it, a segmentation fault will very likely occur, assuming that the value now there represents a memory address out of your control.  If you happen to end up with an address within your memory space, the result will be an attempt to interpret the bytes located there as a `struct sample_struct`, probably resulting in other problems.

---

Just as a note, do not assume that overwriting the pointer in the sample structure above requires only 21 to 24 bytes; it is possible that the memory allocation for that structure will include additional bytes for alignment purposes unless you instruct the compiler to pack the structure.

Comment: I'm trying to account the alignment bytes by using char-only-types or by calculating the padding myself. Are there any other reasons that the memory location would not next to `bytes`?

Comment: In physical memory its continuos block. Like `bytes` - `padding?` - `next`. So if you would know padding, you may overwrite `next` to value you want. If i understood what do you mean right.

Comment: I don't like this suggestion of likelyhood; to suggest that "any buffer overflow that overwrites a memory address that is later used to access memory can result in a segmentation fault" is quite invalid. An expertly crafted buffer overflow will cause arbitrary code execution, which might end with `exit(0);` as opposed to an invalid access to memory and a signal being thrown. You can see examples of this in vulnerabilities...

Comment: @seb I'm well aware of that.  This is why my answer uses the word *can*.  He's not talking about exploitation.  His question is about segmentation faults and overflows and whether overwriting the RP is the *only* way that can happen.

Comment: @CIsForCookies Yes.  If you are using malloc to allocate the structures, it will either return a failure or *at least* the number of bytes needed.  Dynamic memory management libraries will often give you more than you need (by a few bytes) for alignment reasons.

Comment: Actually I came across this quetstion while trying to exploit buffer overflow. I wanted to know what is the difference between writing to memory A and B (possible answers - different pages, read only memory and so on)

Answer (score 3):

> Does buffer-overflow causes segfault only when an important pointer is
>   overwritten?

No necessary, lets start from beginning. In most processors, memory can be segmented into large chunks or small chunks. A large chunk is typically called a segment. A small chunk is typically called a page.

If you are writing behind the buffer (buffer overflow) and "things" which are overwritten behind this buffer belong to same process, no immediate fault occurs.

```
          SEGMENT n     |    SEGMENT n
           buffer1      |     buffer2
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 'a' | 'a' | 'a' | 'a' | 'a' | 'a' | 'a' | 'a' |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
   ^-----^-----^-----^-----^-----^-----^-----^-------- Writing to variables of same process (UB)
```

---

**SEGFAULT** occurs when buffer which has overflow ends at the end of the memory segment. What lies beyond the segment is, in this processor’s current state anyway, currently undefined. Thus memory accesses in this void will lead to a bus fault. No memory content is available for the processor. It doesn’t know where to go. So in this case the error is an immediate catastrophe.

On **x86** or **ARM** you get `SIGSEGV` when writing to a page that is not in an any mapped area, or a page that was in a memory area that was mapped read-only, or reading from an address that is not in any mapped area.

```
                  END OF SEGMENT
                        |
          SEGMENT n     v    SEGMENT n+1
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 'a' | 'a' | 'a' | 'a' |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
   ^-----^-----^-----^-----^--------------------------- Writing to another segment
                           |
                           Writing here will cause SEGFAULT
```

**SEGFAULT** is often caused when program counter return address (which is on stack behind parameters) has been overwritten, and after pop back to continue after function, program counter jumps somewhere (depends on value which has been written to pointer) and hasnt access to read there.

---

> It was OK even when I overflowed the buffer a little bit

You have overwritten *only* memory belonging to your process (no return address) in same segment, but still it is UB.

> but after entering too much the program crashed.

Yes, you have *probably* written to another segment or overwritten return address.

Comment: From what I know, the _2nd_ segfault you describe is memory access violation. I'm only interested in the the _1st_ kind, i.e. writing into a memory inside the stack segment I own, but overwriting the address the `ret` operations wants to return to...

Comment: Is something bad on fact, that i tried to give you _little bit more_ information? :-(

Comment: Not at all. I welcome it. Just wanted to clarify in case my question was ambiguous

Comment: Actually, on x86 or ARM, the *processor segments* have nothing to do with `SIGSEGV`. Instead you get `SIGSEGV` when writing to a *page* that is not in an any mapped area, or a page that was in a memory area that was mapped read-only, or reading from an address that is not in any mapped area.